# How do I create an object of a class whose name is stored in a string?

Tags: objective-c

When creating an object, we use the syntax

```
Item *xyz = [[Item alloc] init];
```

what if the name of the class i.e. "Item" is stored in a core-data database which can, of course, be brought into a string variable...

How can the object be instantiated?

Comment: Use NSClassFromString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `NSClassFromString(@"ClassName");`

```
Class reqdClass = 
id item = [[NSClassFromString(@"ClassName") alloc]init];
```

To go the other way round, you can use

```
NSString *stringClass = NSStringFromClass([Item class]);
```

To set properties for an object instantiated this way:

```
@try 
{
  [item setValue:@"etc" forKey:@"property1"];
}
@catch (NSException *e) 
{
    if ([[e name] isEqualToString:NSUndefinedKeyException]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"property not recognized");
    }
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile. You cannot use reqdClass as a type.

Comment: btw can it set the properties if I do something like item.property1 = 1;

Comment: it will give me a warning I know but it will run correctly isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it will run correctly as long the property does exist in the class

Comment: Actually, You will not be able to set the property directly this way. I will edit the answer with how you can.

Answer (score 2):

To convert the class to a string:

```
NSString* className = NSStringFromClass([Item class]);
```

then you can store `className`.

To go the other way:

```
Class theClass = NSClassFromString(className);
id    xyz = [[theClass alloc] init];
```